# Showing that $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times\mathbb{Z}_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, group-isomorphism, ring-isomorphism

In a previous exam assignment, there is a problem that asks for a proof that $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times\mathbb{Z}_6$ are **not** isomorphic.

We have $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_6$ if there exists a bijective function $f∶ \mathbb{Z}_{24}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times\mathbb{Z}_6$ such that $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ and $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)  \forall a,b\in R$. Since there are exactly $24$ unique elements in both $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_6$, we can construct a bijective function $f∶ \mathbb{Z}_{24}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times\mathbb{Z}_6$. Consider then
$$\begin{aligned}
&f\left([a]_{24}+[b]_{24}\right) \\
&=f\left([a+b]_{24}\right) \\
&=\left([a+b]_{4},[a+b]_{6}\right) \\
&=\left([a]_{4}+[b]_{4},[a]_{6}+[b]_{6}\right) \\
&=\left([a]_{4},[a]_{6}\right)+\left([b]_{4},[b]_{6}\right) \\
&=f\left([a]_{24}\right)+f\left([b]_{24}\right)
\end{aligned}$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}
&f\left([a]_{24}[b]_{24}\right) \\
&=f\left([a b]_{24}\right) \\
&=\left([a b]_{4},[a b]_{6}\right) \\
&=\left([a]_{4}[b]_{4},[a]_{6}[b]_{6}\right) \\
&=\left([a]_{4},[a]_{6}\right)\left([b]_{4},[b]_{6}\right) \\
&=f\left([a]_{24}\right) f\left([b]_{24}\right).
\end{aligned}$$
It therefore seems to me that this function shows that $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ *is* isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Can someone tell me where I go wrong with this "proof", and tell me how I can show that the rings are *not* isomorphic?

Comment: You are provided a definition of isomorphism between two rings. This does not mean any two rings are isomorphic.

Comment: i think you have constructed a homomorphism between $\Bbb Z_{24}$ and $\Bbb Z_{4} \times \Bbb Z_{6}$. one flaw in your proof is "we can construct a bijective function f" but you didn't verify the bijectivity of f.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you defined $f([a]_{24})=([a]_4, [a]_6)$? This is clearly not a bijection. For example, $[0]_{24}$ and $[12]_{24}$ are mapped to the same element.

The rings are not isomorphic because the additive group of $\mathbb{Z_{24}}$ is cyclic, while the additive group of the other ring isn't. So there can't even be a bijection which only satisfies $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$.

Comment: Is the following a valid proof: $\forall (a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_6$ we have $12(a,b)=((a\cdot3)\dot 4,(b\cdot2)\cdot6)=(0,0)$. So if $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_6$ were isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ then $\forall c\in\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ we would have $12c=0$, which is not the case, since for example $12\cdot 1=12\neq0$,

Comment: @JKalle Looks like a good proof to me.

Comment: @JKalle Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Great, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually say what $f$ is somewhere. These are a bunch of manipulations about what would be true of $f$ if it existed. In particular, you take $f$ to be some bijection between these sets, but you are assuming that $f$ has the additive and multiplicative properties you claim it should without actually writing anything down.

Comment: $f$ would simply be a function that sends each element in $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ to an element in $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_6$. For example $f(0)=(0,0)$ $f(1)=(0,1)$, etc. for each of the 24 elements.

Comment: Sure, but why do arbitrary functions satisfy the additivity and multiplicativity properties? They don't, in general, and in fact, there is no such bijection.

Answer (score 1):

These rings are not isomorphic because their additive groups are not isomorphic. In $(\mathbb{Z}_{24},+)$ there is an element whom order is $24$(i.e. $[1]_{24}$). In $(\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_6,+)$ the orders of the elements are upper-bounded by $12$, in fact:

$$\underbrace{([n]_4,[m]_6)+...+([n]_4,[m]_6)}_{12 \text{ times}}=([12n]_4,[12m]_6)=([4\cdot3n]_4,[6\cdot 2m]_6)=([0]_4,[0]_6)$$

Since a group isomorphism preserves the orders, there cannot be a group isomorphism between $(\mathbb{Z}_{24},+)$ and $(\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_6,+)$(let alone a ring isomorphism!).

In the same way, you can prove this more general result:

$$(\mathbb{Z}_{n}\times\mathbb{Z}_{m},+)\cong(\mathbb{Z}_{nm},+)\iff \text{gcd}(m,n)=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $(\Bbb Z_{24},+)$ has an element of order $24$ and $(\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_6, +)$ does not, the two groups cannot be isomorphic as groups; hence the respective rings cannot be isomorphic as rings.